# The supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority [Hyperledger Fabric]

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, containers, hyperledger-fabric

I'm having trouble connecting my docker compose container using my **orderer0 **instance. The whole error is as follows:

```
UTC 0005 PANI [orderer.common.server] Main -> Failed validating bootstrap block: initializing channelconfig failed: could not create channel Orderer sub-group config: setting up the MSP manager failed: the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: ECDSA verification failure" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "ca.istum.com")
```

Below I show you my **docker-compose-orderer.yaml**:

```
version: "3"

volumes:
  orderer0.istum.com:

networks:
  apnet:

services:
  orderer0.istum.com:
    container_name: orderer0.istum.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:2.1
    volumes:
      - ../system-genesis-block/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ../crypto-material/ordererOrganizations/istum.com/orderers/orderer0.istum.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      - ../crypto-material/ordererOrganizations/istum.com/orderers/orderer0.istum.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
      - orderer0.istum.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    environment:
      # Orderer Specific settings
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENPORT=7050
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      # Orderer TLS settings
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: orderer
    ports:
      - 7050:7050
    networks:
      - apnet
```

A little searching on the web speaks of an incorrect positioning of the certificates. Is that so? How can I check for correct placement?

Many thanks to whoever can help me...

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar problem. When I deleted the generated channel-artifacts, crypto-config folders and restarted the network, the bug disappeared. I think it may be caused by expired crypto files.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).